# Use Navigation Controller as sender

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a Custom Back Button:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
```

which calls:

```
func goBack() {
  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

This works but it is quite clumsy. I don't want to make a method that is already a method of navigationcontroller. Why can't I just make the sender navigationController and set the action as popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigationController!, action: "popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by the following change.

```
action: "popToRootViewControllerAnimated:"
```

Comment: Nice! This works. Excellent. I use this all the time and this will clean up my code.